# Jquery radio button on how to disabled the text field without affecting others

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need help. Im having an issue in jquery that when you click the radio button it should not be affected by the others.

This is my code:

```
<script>
    jQuery("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        if(jQuery(this).val() == "Not Vote Anyone")
        {
            jQuery( ".txtfield" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        } else {
            jQuery( ".txtfield" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Website:

http://devsrver.com/

Comment: You can use like `jQuery("input[name='radio-743']")` for section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found 2 problem in your code.

1. `input[type='radio']` will affect all `radio`.
2. `jQuery( ".txtfield" ).prop` will affect all input field having class `txtfield`

---

There are some other good ways to do it if you agree to modify your html and css but this is the simple Change in js code.

---

```
    jQuery("input[name='radio-743']").change(function(){
       if(jQuery(this).val() == "Not Vote Anyone"){
          jQuery("input[name='RifleDirectorName']").prop( "disabled", false );
       } else {
          jQuery("input[name='RifleDirectorName']").prop( "disabled", true );
       }
    });
```

Similarly you have to do it for `radio-744` and `radio-745`

```
jQuery("input[name='radio-744']").change(function(){
           if(jQuery(this).val() == "Not Vote Anyone"){
              jQuery("input[name='PistolDirectorName']").prop( "disabled", false );
           } else {
              jQuery("input[name='PistolDirectorName']").prop( "disabled", true );
           }
        });




 jQuery("input[name='radio-745']").change(function(){
               if(jQuery(this).val() == "Not Vote Anyone"){
                  jQuery("input[name='ShotgunDirectorName']").prop( "disabled", false );
               } else {
                  jQuery("input[name='ShotgunDirectorName']").prop( "disabled", true );
               }
            });
```

Comment: @vince- are you sure selected answer will work correclty?

Comment: Yes. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using selector `input[type='radio']` it will affected to all the radio buttons. You can try like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery("input[name='radio-743']").change(function(){
       if(jQuery(this).val() == "Not Vote Anyone"){
          jQuery( ".txtfield" ).prop( "disabled", false );
       } else {
          jQuery( ".txtfield" ).prop( "disabled", true );
       }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Still affects that when you click radio button john doe, jane doe, it affects also the B director, C director

Comment: Because of the same `.txtfield` class name. You can add different id selector for all the `txtfield` and use those in `jQuery( ".txtfield" ).prop( "disabled", false );`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add difference attribute on every difference section such as A_Director, B_Director, C_Director. But same attribute on same section. For example:

```
<input type='radio' groupsection='A_Direction'>Note Vote Anymore
<input type='radio' groupsection='A_Direction'>John Doe
<input type='radio' groupsection='A_Direction'>Jane Doe
<input type='text' groupsection='A_Direction'> 

<input type='radio' groupsection='B_Direction'>Note Vote Anymore
<input type='radio' groupsection='B_Direction'>John Doe
<input type='radio' groupsection='B_Direction'>Jane Doe
<input type='text' groupsection='B_Direction'>
```

and javascript should be:

```
<script>
    jQuery("input[type='radio']").change(function(){
        var groupsection = $(this).attr('groupsection');
        if(jQuery(this).val() == "Not Vote Anyone")
        {
            jQuery( ".txtfield[groupsection='"+groupsection+"']" ).prop( "disabled", false );
        } else {
            jQuery( ".txtfield[groupsection='"+groupsection+"']" ).prop( "disabled", true );
        }
    });
</script>
```